# connect node js server to a running php web server

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io, webserver

I'm developing a realtime chat app using node js, socket io which is embedded unto an php app. So basically, running my php app unto my local machine by...

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

and then the node server runs on port 3770 and yet, I was unable to connect to my node server. Tried...

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000/my-php-app/:3770');
```

Seems, i put the wrong web socket url. Any help, ideas?

Comment: Try using http://localhost:3770. You have two different servers listening on two different ports. Each will have a unique URL

Comment: so i just do localhost:3770 on the browser?

Comment: its now working thank you!